# pip cmake Failed to build dlib package

Tags: python, installation, dlib

I'm trying to install `dlib` using cmd.

I installed `cmake`, `wheel`, `opencv-python`, `cv2` and `face_recognition` successfully,
but I have trouble to install `dlib`.

If tried `pip install dlib` but it's not working.

I also download `dlib-19.22.0.tar`.

I'm getting this error message:

```
Collecting dlib
  Using cached dlib-19.22.0.tar.gz (7.4 MB)
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
  Building wheel for dlib (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'd:\program files\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\washi\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_kij9b6z\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\washi\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_kij9b6z\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\washi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-yhq98ysd'
       cwd: C:\Users\washi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_kij9b6z\dlib\
  Complete output (55 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  package init file 'tools\python\dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
  running build_ext
  Building extension for Python 3.9.4 (tags/v3.9.4:1f2e308, Apr  6 2021, 13:40:21) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)]
  Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\washi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_kij9b6z\dlib\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\washi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_kij9b6z\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.9 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=d:\program files\python39\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\washi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_kij9b6z\dlib\build\lib.win-amd64-3.9 -A x64'
  -- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
  -- Selecting Windows SDK version  to target Windows 10.0.19041.
  -- The C compiler identification is unknown
  -- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (project):
    No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.



  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (project):
    No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.

--Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

  
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
  Running setup.py clean for dlib
Failed to build dlib
Installing collected packages: dlib
    Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
```

Comment: Did you install C++ Cmake tools for Windows

Comment: No, but installed cmake using pip install cmake  and set path variable also. It's need??

Comment: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-install-dlib-library-for-python-in-windows-10-57348ba1117f. this will help you

Comment: Yes! You need a compiler to read c++ files. Dlib is written in c++

Comment: Thank You @sujay I will Try..

Comment: Thank you @Sujay It's working.. thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: Welcome, happy to hear that